# how to grep only lines that start with specific word in Mac?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, sublimetext2

I have a text file.

I want to grep all lines that **starts** with specific word `"length="

which line in terminal \ using sublime can I run to get only these lines?

text:

```
   }, {
      "path" : "{\"segmentId\":22439323,\"nodeId\":18437268,\"x\":-71.205646,\"y\":42.38619}",
      "distance" : 2744,
      "length" : 73,
      "instruction" : {
        "opcode" : "CONTINUE"
      },
      "crossTime" : 5,
      "additionalInstruction" : null,
      "detourSavings" : 0,
      "isToll" : false,
      "knownDirection" : true
    }, {
      "path" : "{\"segmentId\":67031059,\"nodeId\":18404240,\"x\":-71.206302,\"y\":42.38574800000001}",
      "distance" : 2749,
      "length" : 9,
      "instruction" : {
        "opcode" : "CONTINUE"
      },
      "crossTime" : 1,
      "additionalInstruction" : null,
      "detourSavings" : 0,
      "isToll" : false,
      "knownDirection" : true
    }, {
```

Comment: In your text I didn't see any `length=` text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you need to find the lines with `"length" :` this does the work:

```
 grep '^\s*"length" :' yourfile
```